# Photoelectric current vs anode potential

Tags: photoelectric-effect, photon-emission

Attached is the graph of photoelectric current vs Anode potential as given in my book for same intensity and different frequencies of incident light for the same metal(hence same work function).

In my opinion this graph isn't the graph for the conditions as mentioned rather, it should be for light with same number of photons incident per unit time per unit area(n), with different frequencies.

$I=nh \nu$, where I is the intensity. As $\nu$ is different, $I$ is also different.

In my opinion, the graph for 
photoelectric current vs Anode potential  for same intensity and different frequencies of incident light for the same metal should be as attached in the free hand drawn diagram as drawn by me(I couldn't find any reference regarding the diagram I got).

Could someone please explain whether my book or I or neither is correct?
All my other reference books also seem to suggest the same as given in my book.

P.S. I found few other similar questions asked here before but none of which could answer my query.

[image: Graph from my book]
[image: graph according to me]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.
What you drew can be confirmed from here:
[Stopping Potential vs Frequency](https://www.toppr.com/guides/physics/dual-nature-of-radiation-and-matter/experimental-study-of-photoelectric-effect/)

Comment: Oh ok thank you

Comment: I am still not entirely convinced. There isn't much explanation or details regarding the conditions mentioned. Further, at the bottom of the page, the  same thing as mentioned in my book is mentioned. To add to that, the video given in the link also says the same thing at around 14mins